# Always exist an finite positive measure set contains in a positive measure set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was showing Holder inequality for $p =1$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$

that is $|\int fg|\le \|f\|_1\|g\|_\infty$,if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with Lebesgue measure.

We know the equality actually holds for $f = \text{sgn} g$

In the proof,since $A = \{|g(x)|>\|g\|_\infty -\epsilon\}$ must have positive or $\infty$ measure(with $0<\epsilon<\|g\|_\infty$)

If $m(A)<\infty$ this case is simple,we can just take $f =\text{sgn}g$ then it contains in $L^1$

If $m(A) = +\infty$ this case we need to take a finite measure set $B$ with $0<m(B)<\infty$ define $f = \text{sgn}g$ only on $B$ to make $f\in L^1$

the question is here,why always **exist** such positive measure set $B$ in between that has finite measure? do we need to use $\sigma-$finite of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

My attempt,since $\sigma-$finite of $\mathbb{R}^n$ we can parition $A = \bigcup_i (A\bigcap E_i)$ at least one of them has positive measure so take one of them.such that $0<m(A\bigcap E_i)<\infty$

Comment: Note that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}m(A\cap B_n(0))=m(A).$$ I think the argument of partitioning $\Bbb R^n$ is fine as well.

Comment: A measure with the property that if $m(A) = +\infty$ then there is $B\subseteq A$ such that  $0<m(B)<\infty$ is called a *semi-finite measure*.  All $\sigma$-finite measures are semi-finite. But there are semi-finite measures that are not $\sigma$-finite measures.